# JQuery and JSON - Add element

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON variable defined as:

```
var myCollection = {
  "data": [
    { "name":"Joe", "id":"1" },
    { "name":"Bill", "id":"2" },
    { "name":"Dave", "id":"3" }
  ]
};
```

I have a JavaScript function that is responsible for adding items to the data element in myCollection. However, I'm not sure how to add a name/id pair to the collection via JavaScript. Can someone show me how to add to a JSON collection via JavaScript?

Thank you!

Comment: FYI you can use numeric data in JSON without quoting it. So `{ "name":"Joe", "id":1 }` is still valid JSON.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can simply call the push method on the "data" array:

```
myCollection.data.push( { "name":"Jim", "id":"4" } );
```